# Git submodule add to an existing non empty folder

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'm trying to add a git repo with our corporate wp plugins to a wp project as a submodule:

```
git submodule add git@bitbucket.org:company/our-wp-plugins.git htdocs/wp-content/plugins/
```

Firstly I got this error:

> 'htdocs/wp-content/plugins' already exists in the index

So I removed it from the index with `git rm -r --cached htdocs/wp-content/plugins`, but this time I got another error:

> 'htdocs/wp-content/plugins' already exists and is not a valid git repo

Could I add somehow a submodule to an existing non-empty folder without creating a new subfolder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could I add somehow a submodule to an existing non-empty folder without creating a new subfolder?

No, a submodule will create its own root folder (which is actually a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, a [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) of the parent repo)

Make sure the `.gitmodules` has not already registered that path, and check the content of `.git/modules` folder, before attempting another `git submodule add`.